# Django channels 2.0 websocketbridge.js 403 when self.code(code=1007)

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

I am running django channels 2.0 for a chat room. During connect, I check the room name. If it does not exist, I reject the connection using self.code(code=1007). The ASGI logs show a successful reject as below:

```
WebSocket REJECT /ws/discuss/asdf/asdf1
```

However, on the client side the js library websocketbridge (stock from the installation) throws an unexpected exception, as below:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

On printing to console the received argument. I get the following:

```
CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1006...
```

I would like to catch the error code 1007 thrown by the consumer in the front end, so that I can handle the rejection gracefully.

Any help will ge greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake I was making is that in the connect method of the consumer, I was not accepting the questions by using self.accept(). I first accepted the connection and after evaluating conditions issued a self.close(code=4004). I maybe wrong, but I would expect to not accept the connection, till the conditions are met.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have the same issue, that no matter what code I specify in self.close, the CloseEvent is always:
`CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1006...`

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, this helped me out too. I raised this question in the Django Users group and it *is* the expected behavior:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/4BEbwPTP2gs
A custom close code can only be returned after the socket has been accepted. Closing it before acceptance causes http 403 to be returned and the close code is then browser specific (but often 1006).